# jQuery find with only one element in the result set

Tags: jquery

How does jQuery function that even though `find` returns a collection of DOM elements, if that result set contains just one element, I am able to access its data attributes?

So, if I have the following:

```
<div>
<input class="user-input" data-user-id="2"/>
</div>
```

And I do:

```
var userInputs = $('div').find('.user-input');
```

I can do:

```
$(userInputs).data('user-id')
```

I would assume that I would have to do `$(userInputs).first.data('user-id')`

Comment: `find()` will return jquey object, which is javascript array of DOM elements extended with jquery methods

Comment: Why don't I have to do `first` tho? Why can I access the data attribute without doing first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first element is the root of the tree, you need to get the children of the first element.
if the total result set contains only one element, it can be empty or have children with the relevant information then you need to take the first element like in array - [0].
Update your code to support all the scenarios.